# error unexpected symbol in random effect regression model

Tags: r

```
randeffect <- plm(effort SO ~ Stock Price SO + female + student + major + experience + 
                  hardworking, data = data.p, 
                  model = "random", index = c("Manager", "time"))
```

> Error: unexpected symbol in "randeffect <-plm(effort SO"

I don't know what is the problem?

Comment: I dont know how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you provide a minimum working example?

Comment: you can't use space in you variable name

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple columns in your data set whose names include a space (e.g. "effort SO").  You can protect these with back-ticks as follows

```
`effort SO` ~ `Stock Price SO` + ...
```

If you find this a nuisance going forward, you should rename the columns so they don't include spaces (or have other characteristics that make them illegal R symbol names - special characters, starting with a number, etc.).  You can do this automatically via `names(data.p) <- make.names(names(data.p))` if you like.

Comment: I did it thank you , but now I have another error: Warning messages:
1: In summary.lm(object, ...) :
  essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable
2: In summary.lm(object, ...) :
  essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable